# How to make image fill RelativeLayout background without stretching

Tags: android, background, android-relativelayout

In my Android project, I am not quite sure how to make my background image fill the entirety of the `RelativeLayout` root element in XML, which is the size of the screen. I want to be sure that this works for all aspect ratios, so the image will clip vertically or horizontally as necessary. Does someone know how to do this easily? I've only seen questions regarding `ImageView`s and `Button`s, but not really generic `View`s.

My XML file currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/enclosing_rl"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false">
<!-- Other elements -->
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Other than turning your image into a nine patch I don't think this is possible. What you could do instead is-

1. Add an `ImageView` as the first view in your `RelativeLayout`.
2. Set `layout_centerInParent` to `true`.
3. Have the `layout_width` and `layout_height` set to `match_parent`.
4. Then set `scaleType` to `centerCrop`.

That will make sure the image fills the screen without any distortion, but depending on screen size/orientation either some of the top/bottom or left/right of the image may be cut off.

```
<ImageView 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/background" />
```

Any other views in the `RelativeLayout` will appear on top of the `ImageView`, as long as it is the first view in the `RelativeLayout` (when you are in the xml).

Answer (score 13):

Create a bitmap drawable XML resource in your res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/background"
    android:tileMode="repeat" />
```

Use that drawable as background instead of @drawable/background

Answer (score 6):

according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511280/2652368) If you want your `ImageView` fill your `RelativeLayout`,use `align` parameters for `ImageView`.

you can put all of your views to a `LinearLayout` and set `align` parameter to your background `ImageView`:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

     <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/my_background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/my_views"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_views"

        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/my_views"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    <!-- stuff -->
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its smart and 100% working answer is to set the property scaleType of image view !

```
 android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```