# ImageView won't fill parent

Tags: android, scrollview, android-relativelayout

I have a ScrollView on one of my screens.  I want the right edge to have a shadow.  I decided the easiest way to do this was to make the child of the ScrollView a RelativeLayout, and have two children of the RelativeLayout -- one being a LinearLayout that will house the layout of the screen, and the second View being the shadow.

Like so...

```
<ScrollView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:scrollbars="none" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical" >
                <!-- stuff -->
                </LinearLayout>

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:src="@drawable/shadow"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't quite work.  The ImageView is forcing its dimensions to be the size of the image file.  It will not stretch vertically to be the height of the RelativeLayout.  I've also tried "match_parent" to no avail.  The image is a 9-patch.

Ideas?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Applying drawable content as the source of an `ImageView` somewhat carries with it an inherent requirement that you want the view to do what it can to accomodate the content without modifying the content itself very much.  Typically, this is the behavior you would want out of an `ImageView`.

What you really want is the behavior you get by setting drawable content as the `background` of a view, for which you don't really need `ImageView` at all.  A background is designed to simply stretch, fill, etc. to whatever size the view is. Also, since you are using `RelativeLayout` you can tell the view to match the bound of the view you are shadowing by adding an `id` and some extra `layout_align`parameters.

```
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/content_layout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            <!-- stuff -->
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="11dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignTop="@id/content_layout"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@id/content_layout"
                android:background="@drawable/shadow"
                />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I've already tried this (though I had to specify the width to be 11dip, otherwise it didn't show at all) to no avail

Comment: Edit, had a better idea.  You are correct on the fixed size, without any content inside (of which a background doesn't count) the view can't measure `wrap_content` correctly.

Comment: The only think I can think to do is to grab the View in code, get the height of the screen, and set the height of the View to be the same.

Comment: Does the above example not work either?  The alignTop and alignBottom properties should handle all that for you.

Comment: Yup, the alignTop combined with the alignBottom made it work.  The solution I proposed in my previous comment did, too; but yours is simpler.

Answer (score 9):

try this

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />
```

here is what I get

[image]

and code id

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <!-- stuff -->
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:scaleType="fitXY" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: scaleType did not solve the issue.  To make sure the ImageView wasn't sizing correctly, I changed the background to the color red.  The ImageView is only the height of the image set as the src.  It does not appear to be interested in being match_parent or fill_parent.

Comment: are you notice I have change `src` with `background`? :) Using `src` you can never able to achieve what you want.

Comment: Switching src to background did not work either.  In fact, I've already tried this same thing with a regular View and a LinearLayout instead of an ImageView.

Comment: with this also put `android:fillViewport="true"` of your scroll view.

Comment: Someone else already suggested fillViewport, but it did not solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, fillViewport only applies to direct children, though.

Comment: No, but another answer has solved it.  It looks like, from your image, your solution solves the problem.  For some reason, I am seeing different results.  I did everything the same (as far as I can see) and my image did not stretch vertically.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with the `ImageView` or 9-patch itself, but rather with the fact that you're wrapping everything in a `ScrollView`. A `ScrollView` will automatically force its <strike>children</strike> direct child to wrap its content, no matter whether you tell it to `FILL_PARENT` or `MATCH_PARENT` - both do exactly the same thing by the way; the only difference is the name, which reflects better the actual behaviour of the flag.

Fortunately `ScrollView` provides a way to force it to fill the viewport with a flag, which will make the behaviour pretty similar to setting `FILL_PARENT` to a regular view. Either add the attribute [`android:fillViewport`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#attr_android%3afillViewport) or use [`setFillViewport()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html#setFillViewport%28boolean%29) from code.

**Edit:** Just to be clear, you need to set that flag on the `ScrollView`. Also, if it's the `ScrollView` that should have the shadow, can you not send your 9-patch as background to it? I suppose it does depend on what your actual image looks like. Regarding you comment: yes, the RelativeLayout is flexible in terms of positioning and sizing children, but any child will still be bound to the size of its parent.

I do have the feeling that some of us may be working towards something different than what you have in mind. It would definitely help to clarify things with a simple drawing.

Comment: Unfortunately, fillViewport did not solve my issue.  Also, the ImageView is not the direct child of the ScrollView.  The RelativeLayout is.  I should then be able to make any child of the RelativeLayout fill_parent/match_parent.

Comment: @MH. What you are saying is correct, but only with regards to the child of the `ScrollView`, which here is the `RelativeLayout`.  This constraint does not go beyond that down the hiararchy chain.

Comment: @Devunwired: Sorry about the phrasing earlier, I should've been a bit more careful and said "its direct child" in stead of "children". Fixed in my answer. I still think `fillViewport` will be a solution to your problem, but to avoid any confusion, it would be great if the TS could mock up a little drawing.

Answer (score 0):

You wanted a Shadow towards the right of your image, Then use single layout with `Horizontal Orientation`, It's good that you have decide to use Relative Layout. Use

```
android:orientation="vertical"
```

inside this layout, add those two images. If you still have a doubt, give me those two images or sample images, i will give you the code