# ImageView not stretching (Android)?

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-relativelayout

I have an ImageView inside a RelativeLayout. the ImageView's source is a .png file. The problem is that android is not scaling the image up or down when tested on devices with different resolutions. I read in the android documentation that android automatically scales the image up or down to fill the screen, but this is not happening. What could be the problem? I'm new to android, sorry if this question is dumb, I searched a lot but couldn't find a solution.

EDIT: The XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
     >

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/example" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 2: The XML layout I need to stretch:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar" 
    android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
        android:clickable="false"

        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/volbar" />



    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/head" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="33dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:text="@string/press_to_update" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:clickable="false"
              android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/frag11"
         />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView9"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:contentDescription="@string/p"

        android:src="@drawable/base" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: check if there is any transparent padding in the image

Comment: @StinePike No, there is no padding in the image

Comment: @vergilcorleone Not stretching in the sense..? you want image to occupy entire screen?

Comment: @vergilcorleone Then set height and width `match_parent`

Comment: @Pragnani Can't do that, as I'll be using this concept in a layout with multiple imageviews later, and adding match_parent won't work there

Comment: @vergilcorleone .. what do you exactly want? post your design .. then we may understand that

Comment: @StinePike It will be just like the above XML, but with more ImageViews, one below the other, in LinearLayout fashion.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

use `android:scaleType="fitXY"` in the layout

**EDIT**

if you want the image to occupy whole screen then use

```
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but this adding this isn't changing anything. I'll add the XML as an edit.

Comment: suggest `match parent` as `fill parent` is deprecated

Comment: @StinePike I'll be using this concept in a layout with multiple imageviews later, and adding match_parent won't work there, any other way?

Comment: @vergilcorleone then your question title is wrong... it is stretching perfectly .. but you can not realize.. as the view is smaller.

Comment: Yes your answer was right. But can you tell me how to stretch to fill screen when multiple imageviews are involved?

Comment: @vergilcorleone It will be helpful if you post a image of your design.. that means the structure of layout you want

Comment: NO not the xml .. I was talking about what design you want.. just draw a design you want and post here

Comment: @StinePike Added the design running on the emulator. It is made up of multiple imageviews, and as you can see, it is not stretching to fill the screen.

Comment: ok you can use linearlayout with weight instead of wap_content.... or you can use bigger images.. as your images ar ento big enough.. so the view is also showing small

Comment: @StinePike But I want them to stretch to fill the screen. There must be a way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28521/discussion-between-stinepike-and-vergil-corleone)

Comment: The problem was solved by using the android:gravity and android:weight attribute, for any future visitors.

Answer (score 1):

Refer this,

**

```
<ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                ***android:scaleType="fitXY"***
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                />
```

**

[ImageView won't fill parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11510804/imageview-wont-fill-parent)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"

android:layout_height="match_parent"

 >
```

```
    android:id="@+id/imageview1"

    android:layout_width="match_parent"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:clickable="false"

    android:contentDescription="@string/p"

    android:background="@drawable/example" />
```