# How can I draw circle around google map?

Tags: android, xml, view

How can I make something like this:

[image]

and perhaps go through animation in this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: post your xml code

Comment: follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29457207/android-google-map-circle-shape

Comment: It's just a fragment with MapFragment class. I want to draw circle frame at first  time

Comment: Just looking at this, it would violate the terms of use for Google Maps, as it hides the Google logo.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33729066/how-to-hide-google-logo-from-google-maps-by-adding-overlaid-image-on-google-maps

Comment: Okay, I move logo(with help setPadding()). But how I can make this animation?